# The mail() function is not working in PHP

Tags: php, smtp

**php.ini**

```
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_from = myemailaddress@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe" -t"
```

**sendmail.ini**

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server=localhost
smtp_port=25
smtp_ssl=auto
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=myemailaddress
auth_password=mypassword
force_sender=myemailaddress
```

I had read the previous questions and took the answers as references then although I configured the settings in the code above the mail sending function still could not work. May I ask what is the best way to configure `SMTP` and `smtp_port` in order to enable its function to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Your server (loalhost) is not setup to connect to the mail network and send mails.
Consider authenticating yourself to an external mail server. For example using
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

If you want to send from myemailaddress@gmail.com, the gmail.com domain, you can use this https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600 for the configuration options.

Comment: Any ways to verify my SMTP?

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a shared server? Some hosting companies block access to the mail function.

Comment: I received the error message: ```Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()```